# Documentation versioning for GitHub projects

Tags: github

What is the recommended approach on GitHub to organizing documentation when working on a new version that represents a major rewrite?

In my project [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) I rely on `jsDoc` to generate [all the documentation](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/), and then publish it into `gh-pages`, as one usually does.

And while working on a new version that's a major rewrite and a documentation change, what is the best approach to making the new/unreleased documentation available? -

**1.** Should I simply create a separate repository just for the sake of publishing updated documentation there?

**2.** Should I use an external hosting/solution altogether?

**3.** Is there any GitHub feature that will let me publish more than one documentation version?

---

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1):

This is feasible using [Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) along with a static site generator (SSG) of your choice such as [VuePress](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/), [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/), [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) etc.

In its simplest form, create a GH action to generate the static site folder of the branch/release, then push the folder to corresponding folder in the branch pointed to by GH pages, say *gh-pages*. One of the branches/releases should be pushed to root. [GitHub Pages Deploy Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-github-pages) can be helpful. Add a dropdown list of versions to your static website pointing to the matching folder.

Example:

- [GitHub action](https://github.com/bcgov/NotifyBC/blob/main/.github/workflows/ghPages.yml)
- [dropdown list implemented by Vue component](https://github.com/bcgov/NotifyBC/blob/main/docs/.vuepress/components/versions.vue)
- [rendered site powered by GH pages](https://bcgov.github.io/NotifyBC/)